# Problems using dual resolver

Tags: ivy

I am using dual resolver and having a problem.

Following is what I get when I run through ant in debug and verbose mode( http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/axis2/axis2/working@commons-lang/axis2-working@commons-lang.jar )

```
[ivy:retrieve]  resolved ivy file produced in c:\temp\ivy\resolved-stratus-stratus-working@WPRMW07536F4BS.xml
[ivy:retrieve] :: downloading artifacts ::
[ivy:retrieve]  [NOT REQUIRED] config#ego;4.3.1!ego.conf
[ivy:retrieve]   trying [http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/axis2/axis2/working@commons-lang/axis2-working@commons-lang.jar]
[ivy:retrieve]      tried [http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/axis2/axis2/working@commons-lang/axis2-working@commons-lang.jar]
[ivy:retrieve] HTTP response status: 404 url=[http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/axis2/axis2/working@commons-lang/axis2-working@commons-lang.jar]
[ivy:retrieve] CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=[http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/axis2/axis2/working@commons-lang/axis2-working@commons-lang.jar]
[ivy:retrieve]  ibiblio: resource not reachable for axis2#axis2;working@commons-lang: res=[http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/axis2/axis2/working@commons-lang/axis2-working@commons-lang.jar]
[ivy:retrieve] WARN:    [NOT FOUND  ] axis2#axis2;working@commons-lang!axis2.jar (235ms)
[ivy:retrieve] WARN: ==== commons-lang: tried
[ivy:retrieve] WARN: ==== ibiblio: tried
[ivy:retrieve] WARN:   [http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/axis2/axis2/working@commons-lang/axis2-working@commons-lang.jar]
[ivy:retrieve]  [NOT REQUIRED] axis#axis-saaj;1.4!axis-saaj.jar
[ivy:retrieve]  [NOT REQUIRED] axis#axis-wsdl4j;1.5.1!axis-wsdl4j.jar
```

Can you please tell me what is wrong with my ivysetting file or wrong with ivy file?

Following is an excerpt from ivysettings.xml

```xml
<dual name="dual4">  
    <filesystem name="commons-lang">  
        <ivy pattern="${localRepositoryLocation}/[module]/ivy/ivy.xml"/>            
    </filesystem>  
    <ibiblio name="ibiblio" m2compatible="true" usepoms="false" />
</dual>
```

The problem (may be) is for each and every dependancy that I defined I have seperate ivy.xml and just one resolver as above? Like just for an exampe, for axis2.jar I have two dependancies in another ivy.xml, the dependencies are axis-saaj and axis-wsdl4j.

Comment: What dependencies are you trying to retrieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell without more information but it seems like axis2 is not available in ibiblio with an org name of "axis2" and a module name of "axis2".  I say that because of this line:

```
[ivy:retrieve] ibiblio: resource not reachable for axis2#axis2;
```

Find the line in your ivy.xml that looks like this:

```
<dependency org="axis2" name="axis2" rev="1.5.4"/>
```

and try changing it to something like this:

```
<dependency org="org.apache.axis2" name="axis2" rev="1.5.4"/>
```